# Azure blobstorage sas key is unsafe in angular application

Tags: c#, html, angular, azure-blob-storage

Im trying to get images in my angular application using azure blob storage with sas keys.
But I'm always getting unsafe error in my console. I have also tried using a sanitizer but that doesnt work.

This is my code:

```
sanitizeImageUrl(imageUrl: string): SafeUrl {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(imageUrl);
}

  getFile(id: number): string {
    this._exportDataService.getFileFromTalent(id).subscribe(val =>{
      this.file =  val;
  });
    return this.file
  }
```

```
<nz-list nzGrid>
  <div nz-row>
    <mat-selection-list #talentList (selectionChange)="handleSelection()">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let talent of talents" [value]="talent.id">
        <div *ngIf="isImage(talent)">
          <p id="title">{{ talent.title }}</p>
          <img [src]="sanitizeImageUrl(getFile(talent.id))" alt="image of talent" />
        </div>
        <div id="textTalent" *ngIf="isText(talent)">
          <p id="title">{{ talent.title }}</p>
          <p>{{ talent.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="isVideo(talent)">
          <p id="title">{{ talent.title }}</p>
          <video controls>
            <source [src]="talent.item.url" type="video/mp4" />
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
          </video>
          <!--<iframe [src]="talent.item.url">
          </iframe>-->
        </div>
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
  </div>
</nz-list>
```

I also log the link to the console and there it's the correct link (I can click on it and i will get the image). Also if i copy the link from the console and paste it directly in the image, the correct image will be shown, so I think that the link is correct.
This is the console log without using sanitize, if I use sanitize it just adds "localhost:..." to it.
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Have you refer to this ? http://net-informations.com/q/mis/scheme.html